# From ground level, a shooter is aiming at targets on a vertical brick wall. How far is the shooter from the wall?

Tags: trigonometry

From ground level, a shooter is aiming at targets on a vertical brick wall. At the current angle of elevation of his rifle, he will hit a target 20 m above ground level. If he doubles the angle of elevation of the rifle, he will hit a target 45 m above ground level. How far is the shooter from the wall?

My current working out is as follows:

- tanθ = 20/x
- tan2θ = 45/x
- x = 20/tanθ
- x = 45/tan2θ

20/tanθ = 45/tan2θ

20/tanθ = 45/tanθ+tanθ/1-tanθ.tanθ

20/tanθ = 45/2tanθ/1-tanθ^2

My calculations could continue on from here, but I don't believe I am going down the right track as this website (which has had the working out deleted) suggests another process: http://mymathforum.com/trigonometry/28959-trig-againn.html

The answer to the calculation is 60m.

Comment: Here's a guide to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can write $\tan \theta$ as \$\tan \theta \$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way without using trigonometry. The [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) states that $\frac{BD}{DC} = \frac{AB}{AC}$. Let $AC$ be $x$. Here, $DC = 20$, $BD = 45 -20 = 25$, and then $AB = \sqrt{45^2 + x^2}$. Therefore, we have:

$$\frac{25}{20} = \frac{\sqrt{45^2 + x^2}}{x}$$
$$\frac{5}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{45^2 + x^2}}{x}$$

Cross-multiplying, we have:

$$5x = 4\sqrt{45^2 + x^2}$$

Squaring, we have:

$$25x^2 = 16 \cdot 45^2 + 16x^2$$
$$9x^2 = 32400$$
$$x^2 = 3600$$
$$x = +60, -60$$

However, since $x$ cannot be negative, the only solution is $x = 60$.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense! 

Answer (score 1):

Everything you have done so far is correct:

$$\frac{20}{\tan \theta} = \frac{45}{(2 \tan \theta) / (1 - \tan^2 \theta)}$$

Now you can cross-multiply:

$$\frac{40 \tan \theta}{1 - \tan^2 \theta} = 45 \tan \theta$$
$$40 \tan \theta = 45 \tan \theta - 45 \tan^3 \theta$$
$$5 \tan \theta = \color{red}{+}45 \tan^3 \theta$$
$$\tan^2 \theta = \frac{1}{9} (\tan \theta \ne 0)$$

Can you continue? Not all of the solutions are valid.

Comment: Thanks for your help Toby. Regarding this solution, how can what you have calculated equal 60. I understand how you came to your final result, but the final result is wrong from my understanding. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @LachlanEtherton $\tan \theta = \frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: That's fine, however if I do $\theta = \tan^{-1} (\frac{1}{3})$ it does not equal 60 in either radian (0.32) or decimal (18.43). Am I calculating something incorrectly here?

Comment: The ratio between the opposite side and the adjacent side is $\frac{1}{3}$. Since the opposite side is $20$, then $\frac{20}{x} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Okay. Now that makes sense. You would then multiply the pronumeral by 20 to get the length 60m. Appreciate the clarification.